# WebRTC sample for media demo crashing when building on windows 7

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I was searching for android samples which had only media transmission and found out this relevant.

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Take Media [demo sample](http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/webrtc/examples/android/media_demo/)
2. take [videoengine sample](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/src/modules/video_render/main/source/android/java/org/webrtc/videoengine/?r=2163)
3. Club all these in an Android application project on windows 7, build it will get Webrtcdemo.apk

**What is the expected result?**
App should launch perfectly.

**What do you see instead?**
App crashes at the startup stating "**Unfortunately WebRTC Engine Demo has stopped**"

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**
 5. OS: Windows 7, 64 Bit
 6. Eclipse (adt-bundle)
 7. ADT (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030)

**Please provide any additional information below.**
logCat Error Messages:

LogTag:AndroidRuntime
Application Name:org.webrtc.webrtcdemo

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.webrtc.webrtcdemo, PID: 19322
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load webrtcdemo-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.webrtc.webrtcdemo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.webrtc.webrtcdemo-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null   
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
    at org.webrtc.webrtcdemo.NativeWebRtcContextRegistry.<clinit>(NativeWebRtcContextRegistry.java:17)
at org.webrtc.webrtcdemo.WebRTCDemo.onCreate(WebRTCDemo.java:91)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you install NDK and make sure the JNI has been built successfully?

Comment: Any update on this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have built a library file for one arch (ARM) and you could be trying to install it on different type of arch(x86 or MIPS).

EDIT: I don't think you built the library or it was compiled correctly. You should have a .so file in your libs directory. IMO you should be using Ubuntu/OS to build native apps.

Answer (score -1):

Did you install NDK and make sure the JNI has been built successfully?

Comment: NDK is installed and JNI is built successfully. But there is some problem loading the jni with loadLibrary.

Comment: put this as a comment if you can...this is not an answer.

Comment: How do you know that _JNI is built successfully_? Do you see `webrtcdemo-jni` in **libs** folder? Packed into the **apk**?

Comment: The problem is I cannot, it is uneasy to earn reputation to comment.